# Calculating the power of permutations

Tags: permutations

I have this permutation $A$:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
10 & 8 & 5 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 7 & 9
\end{array}\right)
$$

I want to calculate $A^9$.  Is it ok to calculate it in this way?

$$A*A*A*A*A*A*A*A*A$$

where $A*A$ is defined as $A$ composed with $A$.

Thanks much in advance!!!

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thanks, looks much better now.

Comment: Just discovered the hard way what happens when two people edit the same question simultaneously - the earlier bird gets toasted!  GMTA.  Hope my (later) changes are okay.  Great reference on MathJax [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), or see the link "MathJaX help" on the right when you edit.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone I changed yours slightly - the standard two-line notation for permutations does not have a solid line between and has parentheses around it. Left in your right-alignment, which was better than what I had done.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews remarkable how similar our changes were.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write it as the product of disjoint cycles
$$
A = (1, 10, 9, 7, 6) (2, 8, 4) (3, 5),
$$
and then it's much easier, as a $k$-cycle has period $k$, so that
$$
A^9 = (1, 10, 9, 7, 6)^{-1} (3, 5) = (1, 6, 7 ,9 ,10) (3, 5)
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 &2& 3& 4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10\\
6 &2& 5& 4& 3 &7& 9& 8& 10& 1\end{pmatrix}.
$$

**PS** Apologies, I write my permutations left-to-right.

Comment: @XXXX, you're welcome, please note that I have just fixed a mistake in my calculation.

Comment: putting `1` at first position after 5-cycle inversion  really confused me at first. This is valid because we can write cycle elements in any *offset*. Hope this comment will help someone.

Answer (score 3):

That's ok, but it's not the fastest way. The fastest way (without using tools such as Lagrange's theorem) is to calculate by repeated squaring: $A^9 = (((A^2)^2)^2)A$.

**Edit:** Okay, not sure if my way is faster than the solution posted by Andreas (factoring as a product of cycles), I guess both are useful to know.